# Not working on ie 11 getting error SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I am using Angular12 for my web project. As there are some users out there who are still using IE11, I need to make this web project compatible. Adding polyfills for reference.
Anybody got any idea as to why IE 11 fails to run the angular12?

I have already tried changing the target to es5 but no luck.
[Screenshot of error getting in IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9XXd.png)

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */
/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
/******************************************************************
 * Load `$localize` - used if i18n tags appear in Angular templates.
 */
import '@angular/localize/init';
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min';
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js';
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js'; // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'core-js/features/object';
import 'core-js/features/reflect';
import 'reflect-metadata';
/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
import 'web-animations-js'; // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */
/****************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js'; // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Comment: Do you add the [browserslist](https://v12.angular.io/guide/browser-support#configuring-angular-cli-for-compatibility-with-ie11) to support IE11? I made a sample Angular12 app and changed target to `es5` and had the `browserslist`, and didn't change the `polyfills.ts`, it can work well in IE11.